# Proof of unboundedness of a set

Tags: real-analysis, order-theory, supremum-and-infimum

Prove that $\{2^n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ is not bounded.

Proof: By Induction; $2^n \geq n,\forall n \geq 1$.

By Archimedean property $\mathbb{N}$ is not bounded above.

Assume that $\{2^n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ is bounded.

Then $\exists M \in \mathbb{R}\gt 0$

such that $\forall n, n \leq 2^n \leq M$    $ \Rightarrow \mathbb{N} $ is bounded . Contradiction.

How's this?

Comment: You nailed it !

Comment: provided you have actually proved by induction that $2^n \ge n \forall n$

Comment: @PaulSinclair That proof is rather trivial :)

Comment: @Math1000, you've apparently never taught students at Arcane1729's level before. I cannot say how many such statements I've seen accepted without proof as trivial, that were in fact false. Rigor requires examining every statement. That is the point of my comment.

Comment: I didn't say it wasn't worth writing down. Just that the proof itself is...trivial.